# Visual Studio 2019 C++ external dependencies are missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I installed the Desktop development with C++ for Visual Studio 2019 latest version. When I create a new Console App project and the "Hello World" code opens, the editor shows compile errors on #include  and std::cout, as shown below:

[image: Hello World code]

What I noticed is that the External Dependencies folder of the project is empty. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Check the sdk setting in your project's settings.

Comment: Those are not compiler errors, they are intellisense errors. Not sure why they are occuring, but you should also try an actual compile to see if that works or fails.

Comment: @john I tried compiling but it says that there were build errors.

Comment: @Antonio Then post those build errors with the full text. Make sure you look in the Output window, not the Error List window.

Comment: I consider Intellisense and the Error List as potentially misleading. All I trust is the Output window listing the compiler complaints after a build. (There is even a setting somewhere in the options which prevents that the Error List is raised when compiling. So, I assume I'm not the only one with this habit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by just installing the Windows SDK from Visual Studio Installer. I did not install it at first because it was in the optional extensions.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.